# What is this transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Given A and B are two random variables of unknown correlation, we transform these in to two new random variables X and Y with a know correlation $\alpha$ using the following transformation. What is this transformation called?

$$
        \begin{vmatrix}
        X \\
        Y \\
        \end{vmatrix}=\begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 0\\
        \alpha & \sqrt{1-\alpha^2} \\
        \end{vmatrix}\begin{vmatrix}
        A \\
        B \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix
$$
C:=\left(\begin{matrix}1&0\\\alpha&\sqrt{1-\alpha^2}\end{matrix}\right)
$$
happens to be the [Cholesky decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) of the matrix
$$
\Sigma:=\left(\begin{matrix}1&\alpha\\\alpha&1\end{matrix}\right).
$$
That is, $C$ is a lower triangular matrix such that $CC^T=\Sigma$. So if $A$ and $B$ are **uncorrelated** variables with zero mean and unit variance, and we form the random vector
$$
Z:=\left(\begin{matrix}A\\B\end{matrix}\right),
$$
then the product $CZ$ will also consist of random variables with zero mean, and the covariance matrix of the product $CZ$ will be
$$
\operatorname{Cov}(CZ)=E[(CZ)(CZ)^T]=E(CZZ^TC^T)=CE(ZZ^T)C^T=CIC^T=CC^T=\Sigma.$$
So the resulting variables will have unit variance and correlation $\alpha$.